# C# error while calling class

Tags: c#, .net, class

I learned basic and now I want to learn OOP in C#
I have this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace uceni_cs
{
    class Zdravic
    {
        public void pozdrav()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ahoj světe ! ");
        }
    }

}
```

But when I try to call it using this code

```
namespace uceni_cs
{
    class Zdravic
    {
        public void pozdrav()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ahoj světe ! ");
        }
    }
    Zdravic trida = new Zdravic();
}
```

In code `Zdravic trida = new Zdravic();`
is error. A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods.
What I am doing wrong ? I just want to call the class. 
Thanks

Comment: You're instantiating a class outside of a class (inside of the namespace itself).
You cannot do this. You need to instantiate it within another class somewhere.

Comment: Presumably you need to put that in your `main()` method

Comment: You cannot simply write executable statements on namespace or class level. This can only be done on method level. Try creating a new console application and call the line Zdravic trida = new Zdravic(); in the Main method when having written your class.

Comment: c# does not allow you to create global data and function within namespace. you can create objects and function in class or main methods

Comment: Thanks guys, works fine I just needed to put in my main :)

Comment: @FilipBartoš you should include your error message into your post and modify the title accordingly. This would help other people in future who encounter the same problem to find this post, and solve their problem. Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39789762/edit) button below your post to invoke these changes.

Answer (score 3):

In C# there is no such a thing global variable so you can't just create new instance of Zdravic type that does not belong to any class.


 I suggest you to read [General Structure of a C# Program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2a9a9s3.aspx), and c# [Classes and Structs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an entry point to your application and instantiate the class there.

```
class EntryPoint
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Zdravic trida = new Zdravic();

        trida.pozdrav();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your class object in main method and then use the class properties using that object.

```
 Zdravic trida = new Zdravic();
```

in main method of you program/application.